# width in input search not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on an ASP.Net MVC project where I added a search textbox using some bootstrap classes:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form method="g" action="@Url.Action("Index")">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="search" 
                       name="searchTerm"
                       class="form-control"
                       placeholder="Search for..."
                       style="width: 100%;" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

The code above is producing the following result:

[image]

As you can see there is a space between the search textbox and the Search button. I tried to use the inline style="width: 100%;" to have the width of the input search to cover all the length and have the textbox and the search button close each other.

Is something I am missing in the above code?

Comment: Working properly for me here http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/2170/ . Do you have any other CSS which might be affecting the search?

Comment: No repro as in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t36b81p7/. Have you using other CSS which overrides `btn btn-default` or `form-control` class?

Comment: This work for me very well!

Comment: I just edited your code for the snippet by adding the bootstrap library and it is working fine for me

Comment: Following K K suggestion, I found the problem was inside the Site.css that is added as part of the ASP.Net template in Visual Studio. The max-witth was set as 280px; After commenting it, now there is no space between the textbox and the button.

Answer (score -1):

please remove `style="width: 100%;" />`. Because bootstrap has automatically adjusted the width

Comment: That will never cause the issue that he mentioned